# Looking for a quick and easy way to boost +5VDC to +24VDC

Tags: boost

I am looking for a simple IC solution how to boost +5VDC to +24VDC 1A.   Requirements:

- THT (the project is on a 2.54mm(0.1") experimental breadboard)
- low-cost (this is a hobby project, so arround $5 for the whole converter system)
- simple (fewest external elements)
- has been around for a while (most recent chips are delivered to my country mainly by the Farnell, charging high transport prices).

Is this attainable? What are a part number or two, that I can toss in the local electronics shop and get the device working by the afternoon?

Comment: Pretty good discussion. I'm being waiting for the answers.

Comment: Your 1A requirement makes this sort of non-trivial. It means that the switching element has to switch in the order of 10A! (taking overall efficiency and on-off time into account). That means you need a switcher chip, pass FET, inductor, diode, some assorted support stuff, and a very careful layout.

Comment: @ Wouter van Ooijen, what alternative would you propose, fitting the above requirements? I have wall power (which I would like to avoid for safety reasons) and a computer PSU(hence the 5VDC). Also, I could tap the +12VDC rail Would this make the design more peasantry?.

Comment: Yes, absolutely use the 12V rail. It might not be quite non-trivial but it cuts the input current requirements significantly. 24V DC 1A is 24W. If we keep this simply to P=IV and ignore switching efficiency and a saftey margin above 1A for your max output, 24W/5V=4.8A. Using the 12V rail, 24W/12V=2A. Now keep in mind that if you have a 1A load you want to be able to output more than 1A, probably up to 1.5A (36W) to be safe. Switching regulators are generally about 70-90% efficient, so you're losing another ~9W there = 45W total to design for. 45W/5V=9A. 45W/12V=3.75A.

Comment: Why was the question closed? Deriving various voltages from a efficient end cheap(due to economy of scale) computer PSU is an interesting topic. If it is because of the link to a concrete shop - that is for illustrative reasons only, I can remove it, no problem!

Comment: Your question was closed because the specific request for components is subject to localization in both time and place. Therefore your question is too tightly scoped to be helpful to many users. You can still edit it to make it more general, and then ask for it to be reopened.

Comment: Wait, doesn't a computer PSU have both a +12V and a -12V? Not sure if the -12V can take 1A, but if it can...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Note**: *This solution can not provide 1 Ampere output while boosting from 5 Volts, as pointed out by @markrages. Also, the product mentioned is not suggested to be operated beyond a step-up ratio of 1:3, i.e. up to 15 Volts from a 5 Volt source. Hence, this answer does not meet the criteria specified in the original question. **With the amended 12 Volt source, it would work**.*

---

As has been pointed out by @Wouter van Ooijen, one is unlikely to find a simple single-IC solution for boosting a 5 Volt DC source to 24 Volts at 1 Ampere.

An alternative that fits the specified budget **but not the full requirements** is a pre-built adjustable DC-DC boost module such as [this one on eBay](http://www.ebay.com/itm/LM2577-DC-DC-Step-Up-Adjustable-Boost-module-3-5v-to-30V-/130663149921?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item1e6c217161) for $4.49 with free international shipping.

[image: LM2577 Adjustable DC-DC Boost Module]

The module uses the Texas Instruments [LM2577 step-up voltage regulator](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2577.pdf), and incorporates the required inductor and adjustment preset on the board.

Input voltage ranges from 3.5 to 30 Volts, and output can be adjusted from 4 to 30 Volts, **as long as the output is not set to more than 3 times the input voltage**.

Searching on eBay and other sites may yield lower prices for these modules.

Comment: That won't supply 24V @1A.  The input current is limited to 2A continuous.  That's 10W in.  So at perfect efficiency, that's 416 mA out.

Comment: ebay page: "Continuous input current: 2A (good ventilation and cooling conditions the output voltage and input voltage ratio is not greater than 3)"

Comment: For a 1A output @24V, you need at least 4.8A input.  But the switch in LM2577 is only rated for 3A per the datasheet.

Comment: @markrages Fair point which I had missed entirely... Editing my answer to reflect this. Thanks.

Comment: While looking around for similar PCB's I stumbled upon [this](http://dx.com/p/24v-1a-dual-rj45-port-wall-switching-poe-adapter-eu-plug-140097) power adapter, claiming to provide 24V@1A from wall power. Maybe this will enable me to dump the (rather expensive) computer PSU, deriving the 5V CMOS supply from 24 and not the other way around.

Comment: What is the component that reads 470?

Comment: @RyanWhite 470 uH inductor

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty impressed at [Roman Black's simple +5V to +13V voltage boost circuit](http://www.romanblack.com/smps/conv.htm) that uses only extremely common low-cost components.

[image]

It appears to me that replacing the 13V zener with a 24V zener and some relatively minor part value tweaking would produce a +5VDC to +24VDC booster.
It also appears to me that all of the components in this circuit are available in through-hole packages (THT) which some people seem to think is easier to assemble.
A few people can get a (low frequency) switching regulator working on a solderless breadboard. ([Emre](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/24055/lm2596-voltage-regulation-problem), Roman Black, [J. B. Calvert](http://mysite.du.edu/~etuttle/electron/elect63.htm), [Bob Pease](http://www.rfcafe.com/references/electrical/bob-pease-breadboard.htm), etc.).
Alas, solderless breadboards are notorious for causing problems with switching voltage regulators. ( [Bob Pease](http://portal.national.com/rap/Story/0,1562,8,00.html), again. )

A full 1 A output would require swapping out most of the components with higher-current components, and increasing the current limit by reducing the resistance of R2. It might also need a few heat sinks, since it's "only" 72% efficient.
There are several ways to improve the efficiency, but I all the ones I can think of off the top of my head would make it more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

TI's selector gives [a variety of choices](http://webench.ti.com/webench5/power/webench5.cgi?lang_chosen=en_US&VinMin=4.75&VinMax=5.25&O1V=24&O1I=1&op_TA=30) with those requirements including with a LM3478/88/81. They cost about $5 in parts, but that isn't in small quantities and with shipping.