# voltage divider circuit for dc motor

Tags: dc-motor, voltage-divider

I would like to run a 6V dc motor using a 9v battery supply. The motor specification states that current is 150mA at 6V which I calculate to be a resistance of 40 ohms (when I measure the resistance of the motor at rest it is only 6 ohms). Is it okay to just put the motor in series with a 20 ohm resistance to get the required voltage drop ? Is the resistance of the motor likely to change much under different mechanical loads ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the effective electrical resistance of the motor changes very much with a varying electrical load. Plus, when your motor is drawing 6V × 150mA = 0.9W, your resistor is going to be dissipating 3V × 150mA = 0.45W, wasting 1/3 of your available energy. But when the motor is lightly loaded, it will be getting more voltage than it wants.

A small switching regulator to convert your 9V source to 6V for the motor would be a better choice, and more efficient as well.

Comment: [A question on switching regulators](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/53340/9910)

Comment: Is switching the same as PWM ? If so, would I use a pulse width of two thirds ?

Comment: @FunkyOordvork: It is essentially the same, as long as the inductance of the motor is large enough (with respect to the PWM frequency) to smooth the current sufficiently. A switching regulator would have its own inductor to insure that.